# moule.exports of express framework

Tags: javascript, express, oop

```
    function say_yes(){
      console.log("yes")
    }
    Obj={}
    Obj=say_yes
    Obj.something="something"
    Obj.nothing="nothing"
```

IN BROWSER

In the above code if i `console.log(Obj)`,it gives the function expression
In the above code if i `console.log(Obj.something)` or `console.log(Obj.nothing)` ,it gives the property value.
When i call `Obj()` it consoles   `"yes"`

IN NODE
In the above code if i console.log(Obj),it gives

`{ [Function: say_yes] something: 'something', nothing: 'nothing' }`

In the above code if i `console.log(Obj.something)` or `console.log(Obj.nothing)` ,it gives the property value.
When i call `Obj()` it consoles   `"yes"`
I really confused with it is Obj a function?? is a object?? 
I got this doubt after seeing the source code for the `module.exports` of the express framework

Can someone clear my doubts..

Comment: `Obj=say_yes` sets it to the `say_yes` function whats above is overwritten, the lines under it set some properties, what this got to do with moule.exports or express?

Comment: got to path express \ lib \ express.js there you may find the above structured code in the module.exports

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All functions in javascript are actually first-class objects. Those function objects can be called. You can read here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions